# Gradle: создание .jar файла

Tags: java, javafx, gradle, jar

Содержание `build.gradle`:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes ('Main-Class': 'analyser.App',
                    'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '))
        version '0.1.0'
    }
}
```

При попытке запуска .jar файла получаю следующую ошибку:

> Error: Could not find or load main class analyser.App Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Как интерпретировать эту ошибку? Компилятор ничего не знает о JavaFX? Но я использую JDK8, JavaFX поставляется вместе с JDK.

Comment: Используете Linux?

Comment: @Dred, нет, macOS. Извините, что сразу не указал.

Comment: Не страшно. Давно с javaFX работал, но вроде бы тоже так мучился и на Windows. Попробуйте предпоследний совет [отсюда](https://javarush.ru/help/13380). Так как Мак дочка nix, скорее всего нужно добавлять javafx отдельно. Как в градл это делается, не подскажу.

Comment: @Dred, спасибо.

Comment: На одном из проектов используется Fx 7-й версии, она написана на кишках от JRE(используются некоторые библиотеки из jre/lib) пришлось их в отдельный артефакт вынести и подключать к проекту как обычную зависимость (собирается на любой ОС). В вашем случае, что-то похожее, посмотрев из живого кода, в какой библиотеке декларирован `javafx/application/Application`, добавить эту либу в зависимости проекта.

Comment: @keekkenen, спасибо за совет!